# Удалить документ/индекс из Solr

Tags: solr

Используя Solr, я проиндексировал локальную папку с файлами. Допустим, некоторые файлы были удалены. Я делаю повторное индексирование папки, но удаленные файлы все равно остаются в Solr! Как настроить Solr, чтобы удаленные локально файлы удалялись из Solr тоже?